# Building a set of Partner User ID's in a Lead trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Is it possible to build a set of User ID's on Lead? The following is the code I was thinking.  I'm attempting to build these Id's so I can search for them in another Object.. How else could I go about it?

I get an error 
"Loop Variable must be of SOBJECT Lead"

```
trigger PartnerLeadShare on Lead (after insert,after update) {
Set<id>pUserMap=new set<id>();

if(Trigger.isAfter){
  for(User u: Trigger.new){       
           if((u.UserType ==  'PowerPartner') &&(u.IsActive = True)){
            pUserMap.add(u.id);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it a bit more efficiently, I think (untested, but this looks plausible):

```
trigger PartnerLeadShare on Lead (after insert,after update) {
    Set<id>pUserMap=new set<id>();

    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        for (Lead l: Trigger.new) {    
            if ((l.PartnerAccount.UserType == 'PowerPartner') && l.PartnerAccount.IsActive) {
                pUserMap.add(u.id);
            }
        }
    }

    // Whatever else you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got it.. Thanks though

```
Set<id>pUserMap=new set<id>();  
  for(User u: [select id,UserType,isActive from user where UserType = 'PowerPartner' and    IsActive = True]){       
     {
     pUserMap.add(u.id);  
     System.debug('pUserMap ' +pUserMap);
    }
  }
```